# How to get user wise assigned tasks in SQL Server view?

Tags: sql-server

I have an `employee` table with columns:

```
empid, empname
```

Then a `projectplan` table with columns:

```
planid, empid, task, start, end
```

How to create a view which shows like below:

```
Date     Emp1    Emp2           Emp3           Emp4 .. 
------------------------------------------------------------
01-Jun   task1   task2,task3    task2,task4    task1,task5
02-Jun   task1   task2,task3    task6          task7
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please see this article on how to create a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: wow. thanks marc.. how do I do this kind of formatting while typing the question ?! Capitals and T and Is are noted. thanks again.

Comment: read about `pivot` and `sql server dynamic pivot`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your explanation of the task is not so clear. But i'm understand that you can't create the view with a variable columns count. You can create stored procedure with dynamic SQL that produce needed result. Here my sugestion:

```
CREATE TABLE #employee (
  empid int, 
  empname varchar(100), 
  CONSTRAINT PK_employee PRIMARY KEY (empid)
);

CREATE TABLE #projectplan (
  planid int, 
  empid int, 
  task varchar(100), 
  start date, 
  [end] date, 
  CONSTRAINT PK_projectplan PRIMARY KEY (planid)
);

INSERT INTO #employee 
VALUES 
  (1, 'John'),
  (2, 'Mary')

INSERT INTO #projectplan
VALUES 
  (1, 1, 'Task 1', '20160110', '20160112'),
  (2, 1, 'Task 2', '20160113', '20160228'),
  (3, 1, 'Task 3', '20160315', '20160328'),
  (4, 1, 'Task 4', '20160315', '20160328'),
  (5, 2, 'Task 3', '20160315', '20160319'),
  (6, 2, 'Task 4', '20160320', '20160520')

DECLARE @cols nvarchar(MAX) = 
  STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(empname + LTRIM(STR(empid))) 
    FROM #employee 
    FOR XML PATH('')
  ), 1, 1, '')

EXEC ('
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT 
      p.start AS [Date],
      e.empname + LTRIM(STR(e.empid)) AS [Emp],
      STUFF((
        SELECT '','' + task
        FROM #projectplan
        WHERE empid = p.empid
          AND start = p.start
        FOR XML PATH('''')
      ), 1, 1, '''') AS TaskList
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT
        start,
        empid
      FROM #projectplan
    ) AS p
    INNER JOIN #employee AS e ON e.empid = p.empid
  ) AS it
  PIVOT (
    MAX(TaskList) FOR Emp IN (' + @cols + ')
  ) AS pt')
```

Comment: Dmitriy, thanks a ton. It worked exactly the way I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it in a view, if you add new employees you will need to rewrite it. That is why you need dynamic SQL.

At first I created table with dummy data:

```
SELECT * INTO #employee
FROM (VALUES
(1, 'John Smith'),
(2, 'Richard Morris'),
(3, 'Jason Campbell'),
(4, 'Anthony Watson'),
(5, 'Jeff Butler')
) as t(empid, empname)

SELECT * INTO #projectplan 
FROM (VALUES
(1, 1, 'task1','2016-06-01','2016-06-07'),
(2, 2, 'task2','2016-06-01','2016-06-05'),
(3, 3, 'task3','2016-06-01','2016-06-05'),
(4, 4, 'task4','2016-06-01','2016-06-03'),
(5, 5, 'task5','2016-06-01','2016-06-04'),
(6, 2, 'task6','2016-06-02','2016-06-09'),
(7, 3, 'task7','2016-06-03','2016-06-17'),
(8, 5, 'task8','2016-06-02','2016-06-19')
) as t(planid, empid, task, [start], [end])
```

Then I use CTE to get all dates between `MIN([start])` and `MAX([end])`, and another CTE with all employees and there tasks for every date:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT  CAST(MIN([start]) as datetime) as dateStart,
            CAST(MAX([end]) as datetime) as dateEnd
    FROM #projectplan
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  DATEADD(day,1,dateStart),
            dateEnd
    FROM cte
    WHERE dateStart < dateEnd
), res AS (
    SELECT  empname,
            task,
            c.dateStart as [date] 
    FROM cte c
    INNER JOIN #projectplan p
        ON c.dateStart between [start] and [end]
    INNER JOIN #employee e
        ON e.empid = p.empid
)
--And put them into `#final` temporary table
SELECT  r.empname,
        CAST(r.[date] as date) [date],
        STUFF((SELECT ','+task
        FROM res
        WHERE empname = r.empname AND [date] = r.[date]
        FOR XML PATH('')
        ),1,1,'') as tasks
INTO #final
FROM res r
```

So in `#final` table I have:

```
empname         date        tasks
John Smith      2016-06-01  task1
Richard Morris  2016-06-01  task2
Jason Campbell  2016-06-01  task3
Anthony Watson  2016-06-01  task4
Jeff Butler     2016-06-01  task5
John Smith      2016-06-02  task1
Richard Morris  2016-06-02  task2,task6
Jason Campbell  2016-06-02  task3
Anthony Watson  2016-06-02  task4
Jeff Butler     2016-06-02  task5,task8
...etc
```

As you see all employees with crossing between dates tasks are comma separated. Then we PIVOT with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max),
        @query nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns = STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(empname)
FROM #employee
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @query = N'
SELECT *
FROM #final
PIVOT (
    MAX(tasks) FOR empname IN ('+@columns+')
) AS pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Output:

```
date        John Smith  Richard Morris  Jason Campbell  Anthony Watson  Jeff Butler
2016-06-01  task1       task2           task3           task4           task5
2016-06-02  task1       task2,task6     task3           task4           task5,task8
2016-06-03  task1       task2,task6     task3,task7     task4           task5,task8
2016-06-04  task1       task2,task6     task3,task7     NULL            task5,task8
2016-06-05  task1       task2,task6     task3,task7     NULL            task8
2016-06-06  task1       task6           task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-07  task1       task6           task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-08  NULL        task6           task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-09  NULL        task6           task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-10  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-11  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-12  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-13  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-14  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-15  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-16  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-17  NULL        NULL            task7           NULL            task8
2016-06-18  NULL        NULL            NULL            NULL            task8
2016-06-19  NULL        NULL            NULL            NULL            task8
```

As you can see `Richard Morris` got 2 tasks `task2` with dates between `2016-06-01` and `2016-06-05` and `task6` with time interval between `2016-06-02` and `2016-06-09`. So intervals are crossing and `task2,task6` is showing between `2016-06-02` and `2016-06-05`.

Hope this will help you!